# Fetching Date of Type DateTime with BreezeJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, breeze

I'm currently developing an SPA webapplication with BreezeJS. This is all working fine, but I have this question. In my entity I have a table which has a type DateTime, to store the creationdate created with the Entity Framework. This all goes fine but when I fetch the data from the server via Breeze (Server-> to -> client) I get this back in my javascript: `Wed May 8 16:23:32 UTC+0200 2013`

But via Fiddler2 I see it comes in likes this in my JSON: `Created=2013-05-08T16:23:32.038+02:00`

Why does BreezeJS add the day name to it? Anyone now where I can get the raw value so I can format the date?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you currently trying to format the date, and is this just to display it?  If you don't display what Breeze is giving you back then you have to do a (more) complicated parse of the date to get it in a format you want.  Second option is simply use moment.js to format dates for you.

Answer (score 0):

Breeze does not manipulate the day in any way EXCEPT to add a UTZ timezone specifier to any dates **returned** from the server that do not already have one.  This is only done because different browsers interpret dates without a timezone specifier differently and we want consistency between browsers.

Comment: I understand, but can I get the raw data for my own formatting?

Comment: Not sure I understand, you are getting the raw data. A Breeze date is a javascript date, you should be able to use any javascript date library to format a Breeze date anyway you want.

Comment: I understand you now! Yes I see the functions but the values like getDate() or getMonth are all empty! [link]http://s3.postimg.org/q9bno2l77/problem_with_date.png

Test show the date like `Wed May 8 16:23:32 UTC+0200 2013`